# Comparing similar types that don't share any interface

Tags: c#, duck-typing

I have two types that don't share any interface but have similar properties and that I need to compare for equality.

One of them is comming from a 3rd party library and one of them is mine. I obviously cannot add any interface to the foreign type and honestly I don't want to create any wrapper for both of them in order to just use it once for some linq. I prefer to have something that lasts longer and can be reused for other projects.

I used these to types for testing but they might of course have many other properties - and as a matter of fact my two actual types have exactly the same properties as this example:

> ```
> class PersonLib1
> {
>   public string FirstName { get; set; }
>
>   public string LastName { get; set; }
> }
>
> class PersonLib2
> {
>   public string FirstName { get; set; }
>
>   public string LastName { get; set; }
> }
> ```

---

### API

I solved this problem by implementing the `IEqualityComparer<object>` as a `DuckEqualityComparer` - its name comes from the idea of [Duck Typing](https://devopedia.org/duck-typing) - this is, since both types share some common or similar properties they must be the same.

My comparer allows the user to specify the exact types and their comparison logic. The order of the types is not relevant and it tries both combinations.

I used additional blocks of `{}` inside the `Equals` method to be able to reuse the short variable names.

```
class DuckEqualityComparer<Tx, Ty> : IEqualityComparer<object>
{
    private readonly Func<Tx, Ty, bool> _equals;
    private readonly Func<Tx, int> _getHashCodeX;
    private readonly Func<Ty, int> _getHashCodeY;

    private DuckEqualityComparer(Func<Tx, Ty, bool> equals, Func<Tx, int> getHashCodeX, Func<Ty, int> getHashCodeY)
    {
        _equals = equals;
        _getHashCodeX = getHashCodeX;
        _getHashCodeY = getHashCodeY;
    }

    public new bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
        {
            if (x is Tx tx && y is Ty ty && Equals(tx, ty)) return true;
        }
        {
            if (x is Ty ty && y is Tx tx && Equals(tx, ty)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private bool Equals(Tx x, Ty y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
        return _equals(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(object obj)
    {
        switch (obj)
        {
            case Tx x: return _getHashCodeX(x);
            case Ty y: return _getHashCodeY(y);
            default: return 0;
        }
    }

    public static IEqualityComparer<object> Create(Func<Tx, Ty, bool> equals, Func<Tx, int> getHashCodeX, Func<Ty, int> getHashCodeY)
    {

        return new DuckEqualityComparer<Tx, Ty>(equals, getHashCodeX, getHashCodeY);
    }
}
```

Why didn't I use tuples? Because they don't allow me to use other then the default comparer on the property level.

Is this an acceptable solution or is there anything that could be done better?

---

### Example

This is how I use it:

```
var p1 = new PersonLib1 { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
var p2 = new PersonLib2 { FirstName = "JOHN", LastName = "Doe" };
var p3 = new PersonLib2 { FirstName = "Joh", LastName = "Doe" };

var stringComparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
var personComparer = DuckEqualityComparer<PersonLib1, PersonLib2>.Create(
    equals: (x, y) =>
        stringComparer.Equals(x.FirstName, y.FirstName) &&
        stringComparer.Equals(x.LastName, y.LastName),
    getHashCodeX: x => 
        stringComparer.GetHashCode(x.FirstName) + 
        stringComparer.GetHashCode(x.LastName),
    getHashCodeY: y => 
        stringComparer.GetHashCode(y.FirstName) + 
        stringComparer.GetHashCode(y.LastName)
);

personComparer.Equals(p1, p2).Dump();
personComparer.Equals(p2, p1).Dump();

personComparer.Equals(p1, p3).Dump();
personComparer.Equals(p3, p1).Dump();
```

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at [AutoFixture/SemanticComparison](https://github.com/AutoFixture/SemanticComparison) which allows doing this kind of stuff. The documentation is sparse to say the least, but it's rather useful. See [those](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/06/29/IntroducingAutoFixtureLikeness/) [links](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/06/22/ResemblanceandLikeness/) for a usage example.

Comment: @xlecoustillier thanks for the tipp - I see someone else already had a similar idea - I'll use this project for borrowing features and in fact I'm already planning to add a builder with expressions to make the comparer-set-up easier ;-]

Comment: @t3chb0t: Do you change to AutoFixture, or do you still wish some feedback?

Comment: @HenrikHansen I won't change to AutoFixture - I don't like its implementation and I think I/we can make it better ;-) personally I can't stand the specification pattern primarily because of its weird _IsSatisfiedBy_ methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a problem in that you only compare objects of same type (Tx and Tx or Ty and Ty) by reference, but compare by selected properties for objects of different types (Tx and Ty). I wonder if that can lead to unexpected behavior?

If you have the following objects and compare by `FirstName` and `LastName`:

```
  var p0 = new PersonLib1 { Id = 0, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
  var p1 = new PersonLib1 { Id = 1, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
  var p2 = new PersonLib2 { Id = 2, FirstName = "JOHN", LastName = "Doe" };
  var p3 = new PersonLib2 { Id = 3, FirstName = "Joh", LastName = "Doe" };
```

then `p0 != p1` but `p0 == p2` and `p1 == p2` because `p0` and `p1` is of same type where as `p2` is the other type. In other words: you have two different objects of the same type, that are both equal to the same object of another type!

`p0` and `p1` produces the same hash code, so `DuckEqualityComparer<>.Equals()` is called for these objects:

> ```
> public override bool Equals(object x, object y)
> {
>     if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
>     if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
>     if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
>
>     ValidateType(x);
>     ValidateType(y);
>
>     if (Equals((x, y))) return true;
>     if (Equals((y, x))) return true;
>
>     return false;
> }
>
> private bool Equals((object x, object y) t)
> {
>     return t.x is TX x && t.y is TY y && _equals(x, y);
> }
> ```

but unless they are equal by reference, they fall through the other tests, because they all handle objects of different types.

To get it work properly, you'll have to ensure `one-to-one` relationship between objects of `Tx` and `Ty`:

```
  var p0 = new PersonLib1 { Id = 0, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
  var p1 = new PersonLib1 { Id = 1, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
  var p2 = new PersonLib2 { Id = 1, FirstName = "JOHN", LastName = "Doe" };
  var p3 = new PersonLib2 { Id = 3, FirstName = "Joh", LastName = "Doe" };
```

If you compare by just `Id`, or `Id`, `FirstName` and `LastName` in the above `p0` and `p2` are unequal where `p1` and `p2` are equal.

---

A simple "Expression" solution without the Builder could be:

```
  public class MixedEqualityComparer<Tx, Ty> : IEqualityComparer<object>
  {
    List<Func<Tx, Ty, bool>> m_xyEquals = new List<Func<Tx, Ty, bool>>();

    Func<Tx, int> m_getHashCodeX;
    Func<Ty, int> m_getHashCodeY;


    public MixedEqualityComparer(Func<Tx, int> getHashCodeX, Func<Ty, int> getHashCodeY)
    {
      m_getHashCodeX = getHashCodeX;
      m_getHashCodeY = getHashCodeY;
    }

    public MixedEqualityComparer<Tx, Ty> Compare<TProperty>(Expression<Func<Tx, TProperty>> xMemberExpression, Expression<Func<Ty, TProperty>> yMemberExpression, IComparer<TProperty> comparer = null)
    {
      var xmemFunc = xMemberExpression.Compile();
      var ymemFunc = yMemberExpression.Compile();

     comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<TProperty>.Default;

     if (comparer != null)
       m_xyEquals.Add((x, y) => comparer.Compare(xmemFunc(x), ymemFunc(y)) == 0);
     else
     {
       m_xyEquals.Add((x, y) =>
       {
         TProperty xmem = xmemFunc(x);
         TProperty ymem = ymemFunc(y);
         if (xmem != null && ymem != null) return xmem.Equals(ymem);
         return xmem == null && ymem == null;
       });
     }

     return this;
    }

    public new bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
      if (x is null || y is null) return false;
      if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

      return IsEqual(x, y) || IsEqual(y, x);
    }

    private bool IsEqual(object x, object y)
    {
      return x is Tx tx && y is Ty ty && m_xyEquals.All(eq => eq(tx, ty));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(object obj)
    {
      switch (obj)
      {
        case Tx x: return m_getHashCodeX(x);
        case Ty y: return m_getHashCodeY(y);
        default: return 0;
      }
    }
  }
```

**Use Case**

```
  var p0 = new PersonLib1 { Id = 0, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
  var p1 = new PersonLib1 { Id = 1, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
  var p2 = new PersonLib2 { Id = 2, FirstName = "JOHN", LastName = "Doe" };
  var p3 = new PersonLib2 { Id = 3, FirstName = "Joh", LastName = "Doe" };

  var stringComparer = StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
  Func<PersonLib1, int> getXHashCode = x => stringComparer.GetHashCode(x.FirstName) + stringComparer.GetHashCode(x.LastName);
  Func<PersonLib2, int> getYHashCode = x => stringComparer.GetHashCode(x.FirstName) + stringComparer.GetHashCode(x.LastName);

  MixedEqualityComparer<PersonLib1, PersonLib2> personComparer = new MixedEqualityComparer<PersonLib1, PersonLib2>(getXHashCode, getYHashCode)
    .Compare(x => x.FirstName, y => y.FirstName, stringComparer)
    .Compare(x => x.LastName, y => y.LastName, stringComparer);

  Dictionary<object, string> dict = new Dictionary<object, string>(personComparer);
  dict[p0] = "AAA";
  dict[p1] = "BBB";
  dict[p2] = "CCC";
  dict[p3] = "DDD";

  Console.WriteLine(dict.Count); // == 3
```

Comment: I'd love to upvote your answer but I'm not sure I understand what you mean that I _only reference equals objects of same type_. Could you perhaps rephrase it?

Comment: I see it now! This means I need to add a guard against it because it makes absolutely no sense to compare objects of the same type. It's the job of another comparer. The sole purpose of this utility is to compare different objects so `Tx` and `Ty` must not be of the same type. Good catch! ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t: yes, or you should make it possible to compare objects of the same type by selected properties as well, but that will probably lead to other mistakes?

Comment: I don't want it to compare same types but I'm really surprised that this actually does not work :-o I hadn't expected it. That's probably why I didn't have a test for it :-)

Comment: Could you point me to the line(s) that make(s) equality for same types work? Just out of curiosity. I'm going to block this but I'd like to know the reason why it refuses to compare their members. I cannot find this _feature_.

Comment: @t3chb0t: Sorry, I simply don't understand the question? You can only compare equality by reference for objects of the same type (for classes/reference types). For objects of different types you are comparing by selected members (FirstName, LastName etc.) and those members must be selected so that only one `Tx` equals one `Ty`.

Comment: ok, I've found it ;-) after all I think this behaviour is correct. When I define the comparer for `Tx` and `Ty` and try to check whether two `Tx`s are equal then it should yeal `false` because it shouldn't work for these types. I now have added a validation for the arguments so it'll throw if I try to do this. Member comparison only is intended because the objects must not be related. If they are, then a normal comparer would be enough - I'd say case solved ;-]

Comment: @t3chb0t: You can do that, but then the comparer is of limited use, and can for instance not be used as comparer for a dictionary like above in my Use Case. You can use it where you know that the two objects are of different types - but that may be valid for your purpose.

Answer (score 6):

You can shorten the syntax a bit and increase readability by using the `is` or `==` operators instead of `ReferenceEquals`:

```
public new bool Equals(object x, object y)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
    if (x is null || y is null) return false;
    {
        if (x is Tx tx && y is Ty ty && Equals(tx, ty)) return true;
    }
    {
        if (x is Ty ty && y is Tx tx && Equals(tx, ty)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The extra braces to make the variables local to their body is clever, however I cant exactly say I like it, it's very easy to consider the first braces to be part of the if statement above them and it can be made much more readable too if you extract it to a method:

```
public new bool Equals(object x, object y)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
    if (x is null || y is null) return false;
    return CompareObjects(x, y) || CompareObjects(y, x);
}

protected bool CompareObjects(object x, object y)
{
    return x is Tx tx && y is Ty ty && Equals(tx, ty);
}
```

You can also define 2 generic type arguments for the `CompareObjects` methods, to make it more explicit, that you're swapping the types.

> ```
> private bool Equals(Tx x, Ty y)
> ```

Feels weird and out of place in my opinion, you're checking if the values of x and y are null, but you've already done so in `public new bool Equals(object x, object y)` and since it's a private method, that doesn't make much sense, removing this check makes it a simple call to `_equals`, which makes the whole method redundant, you are better off making it `protected virtual`, or just delete it all together

```
protected virtual bool Equals(Tx x, Ty y)
{
    return x != null && y != null && _equals(x, y);
}
```

You also lack null checks for the delegates in the `Create` method, but I assume you've omitted those for simplicity/

Comment: You're right about everything! ;-D There is, however, one thing that bit me when writing comparers before so I now always use the `ReferenceEquals` - sometimes when you're not careful you might create an infinite loop by checking against `null` with other operators - they might call `==` and `Equals` recursively ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t I believe it wont cause such problems as long as we're checking against null, out of curiosity do you happen to have an example where infinite loop is created?

Comment: [Here](https://pastebin.com/7Z5pjxh2) you are :-] It's too easy to make this mistake.

Comment: The swapping with `CompareObjects(x, y)` gave me another idea... one can use tuples for it and create another overload for `Equals`.

Comment: I've just came to the conclustion that changing the parameter order for `Equals` automatically isn't actually such a good idea because some comparisons might not be commutative :-o e.g. I added another overload to the builder that allows the user to specify a custom `Equals` logic and if he uses `x.StartsWith(x)` then swapping the parameters would be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

From the suggested changes I like the one about swapping arguments most so this is actually the only change I've made. To implement it I used a tuple parameter. I decided to stick to `ReferenceEquals` because otherwise when using the equality operator `==` there is a risk of runing into an [infinite loop](https://pastebin.com/7Z5pjxh2). I have also added a helper method `ValidateType` to throw an exception if unsupported types are used and of course a couple of `null`-checks.

```
public class DuckEqualityComparer<TX, TY> : EqualityComparer<object>
{
    private readonly Func<TX, TY, bool> _equals;
    private readonly Func<TX, int> _getHashCodeX;
    private readonly Func<TY, int> _getHashCodeY;

    private DuckEqualityComparer(Func<TX, TY, bool> equals, Func<TX, int> getHashCodeX, Func<TY, int> getHashCodeY)
    {
        _equals = equals;
        _getHashCodeX = getHashCodeX;
        _getHashCodeY = getHashCodeY;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;

        ValidateType(x);
        ValidateType(y);

        if (Equals((x, y))) return true;
        if (Equals((y, x))) return true;
        
        return false;
    }

    private bool Equals((object x, object y) t)
    {
        return t.x is TX x && t.y is TY y && _equals(x, y);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(object obj)
    {
        ValidateType(obj);

        switch (obj)
        {
            case TX x: return _getHashCodeX(x);
            case TY y: return _getHashCodeY(y);
            default: return 0;
        }
    }

    [NotNull]
    public static EqualityComparer<object> Create(
        [NotNull] Func<TX, TY, bool> equals,
        [NotNull] Func<TX, int> getHashCodeX,
        [NotNull] Func<TY, int> getHashCodeY
    )
    {
        if (equals == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(equals));
        if (getHashCodeX == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(getHashCodeX));
        if (getHashCodeY == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(getHashCodeY));
        
        return new DuckEqualityComparer<TX, TY>(equals, getHashCodeX, getHashCodeY);
    }

    private static void ValidateType(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is TX || obj is TY))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Type '{obj.GetType().Name}' is not supported. Objects must be '{typeof(TX).Name}' or '{typeof(TY).Name}'");
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Bonus - `DuckEqualityComparerBuilder`

Creating an equality-comparer is a tedious and error-prone process because you have to think about the `&&` operator between the conditions and you have to specify two `GetHashCode` methods. I'm lazy so I put together a builder that compiles the equality-comparer from expressions. To create it I borrowed code form the [AutoEqualityComparer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/175980/declarative-type-comparer) and its great reviews.

```
public static class DuckEqualityComparerBuilder
{
    public static DuckEqualityComparerBuilder<TX, TY> Create<TX, TY>(TX x, TY y) => new DuckEqualityComparerBuilder<TX, TY>();
}

public class DuckEqualityComparerBuilder<TX, TY>
{
    private readonly ParameterExpression _parameterX = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TX), "x");
    private readonly ParameterExpression _parameterY = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TY), "y");

    private readonly IList<(Expression equals, Expression getHashCodeX, Expression getHashCodeY)> _expressions = new List<(Expression, Expression, Expression)>();

    public DuckEqualityComparerBuilder<TX, TY> Compare<T>(
        Expression<Func<TX, T>> getValueX,
        Expression<Func<TY, T>> getValueY,
        IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null
    )
    {
        comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

        // comparer.Equals(getValueX(x), getValueY(y));
        var equalsFunc = (Expression<Func<T, T, bool>>)((x, y) => comparer.Equals(x, y));
        var equals =
            Expression.Invoke(
                equalsFunc,
                Expression.Invoke(getValueX, _parameterX),
                Expression.Invoke(getValueY, _parameterY)
            );

        // comparer.GetHashCode(getValueX(x))
        var getHashCodeFunc = (Expression<Func<T, int>>)(obj => comparer.GetHashCode(obj));

        var getHashCodeX =
            Expression.Invoke(
                getHashCodeFunc,
                Expression.Invoke(getValueX, _parameterX)
            );

        // comparer.GetHashCode(getValueY(y))
        var getHashCodeY =
            Expression.Invoke(
                getHashCodeFunc,
                Expression.Invoke(getValueY, _parameterY)
            );

        _expressions.Add((equals, getHashCodeX, getHashCodeY));

        return this;
    }

    public EqualityComparer<object> Build()
    {
        var equalityComparer = _expressions.Aggregate((next, current) =>
        (
            equals: ConcatenateEqualsExpressions(current.equals, next.equals),
            getHashCodeX: ConcatenateGetHashCodeExpressions(current.getHashCodeX, next.getHashCodeX),
            getHashCodeY: ConcatenateGetHashCodeExpressions(current.getHashCodeY, next.getHashCodeY)
        ));

        var equalsFunc = Expression.Lambda<Func<TX, TY, bool>>(equalityComparer.equals, _parameterX, _parameterY).Compile();
        var getHashCodeXFunc = Expression.Lambda<Func<TX, int>>(equalityComparer.getHashCodeX, _parameterX).Compile();
        var getHashCodeYFunc = Expression.Lambda<Func<TY, int>>(equalityComparer.getHashCodeY, _parameterY).Compile();

        return DuckEqualityComparer<TX, TY>.Create(
            equalsFunc,
            getHashCodeXFunc,
            getHashCodeYFunc
        );
    }

    public static implicit operator EqualityComparer<object>(DuckEqualityComparerBuilder<TX, TY> builder) => builder.Build();
}

internal static class ExpressionHelper
{
    public static Expression ConcatenateEqualsExpressions(Expression equalsExpressionX, Expression equalsExpressionY)
    {
        // equals && equals
        return
            Expression.AndAlso(
                equalsExpressionX,
                equalsExpressionY
            );
    }

    public static Expression ConcatenateGetHashCodeExpressions(Expression getHashCodeExpressionX, Expression getHashCodeExpressionY)
    {
        // x * 31 + y
        return
            Expression.Add(
                Expression.Multiply(
                    getHashCodeExpressionX,
                    Expression.Constant(31)
                ),
                getHashCodeExpressionY
            );
    }
}
```

---

I also wrote a couple of tests to have a proof that it actually works and I like the fact that it's even possible to compare named types against anonymous ones.

```
using static Assert;
using static ExpressionHelper;

[TestClass]
public class DuckEqualityComparerTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Equals_CanCompareTowNamedTypes()
    {
        var p1 = new PersonLib1 { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
        var p2 = new PersonLib2 { FirstName = "JOHN", LastName = "Doe" };
        var p3 = new PersonLib2 { FirstName = "Joh", LastName = "Doe" };
        var p4 = new PersonLib2 { FirstName = default, LastName = "Doe" };

        var comparer =
            new DuckEqualityComparerBuilder<PersonLib1, PersonLib2>()
                .Compare(x => x.FirstName, y => y.FirstName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                .Compare(x => x.LastName, y => y.LastName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                .Build();

        IsTrue(comparer.Equals(p1, p1));
        IsTrue(comparer.Equals(p2, p2));

        IsTrue(comparer.Equals(p1, p2));
        IsTrue(comparer.Equals(p2, p1));

        IsFalse(comparer.Equals(p1, p3));
        IsFalse(comparer.Equals(p3, p1));
        IsFalse(comparer.Equals(p1, p4));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Equals_CanCompareTwoAnonymousTypes()
    {
        var comparer =
            DuckEqualityComparerBuilder
                .Create(
                    new { FirstName1 = default(string), LastName1 = default(string) },
                    new { FirstName2 = default(string), LastName2 = default(string) }
                )
                .Compare(x => x.FirstName1, y => y.FirstName2, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                .Compare(x => x.LastName1, y => y.LastName2, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                .Build();

        IsTrue(comparer.Equals(
            new { FirstName1 = "John", LastName1 = "Doe" },
            new { FirstName2 = "JOHN", LastName2 = "DOE" }
        ));

        IsFalse(comparer.Equals(
            new { FirstName1 = "Johny", LastName1 = "Dope" },
            new { FirstName2 = "JOHN", LastName2 = "DOE" }
        ));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Equals_CanCompareNamedAndAnonymousTypes()
    {
        var comparer =
            DuckEqualityComparerBuilder
                .Create(
                    default(PersonLib1),
                    new { FirstName2 = default(string), LastName2 = default(string) }
                )
                .Compare(x => x.FirstName, y => y.FirstName2, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                .Compare(x => x.LastName, y => y.LastName2, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                .Build();

        IsTrue(comparer.Equals(
            new PersonLib1 { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" },
            new { FirstName2 = "JOHN", LastName2 = "DOE" }
        ));

        IsFalse(comparer.Equals(
            new PersonLib1 { FirstName = "Johny", LastName = "Dope" },
            new { FirstName2 = "JOHN", LastName2 = "DOE" }
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this answer the most because it provides the easiest API. All the ugly HashCode calculations are cleanly hidden below the surface so that the user of the Builder class can concentrate on the interesting part on the application layer.